# Convert linq to sql with having statement

Tags: sql, linq, having

How can I convert this `sql` to `linq`

```
SELECT FK_SubjectId, LectureDays 
FROM tbl_TimeTables 
GROUP BY FK_SubjectId, LectureDays
HAVING(COUNT(Period) < 6)
```

I couldn't see the answer in the link provided, all i just want is to interpret the group by and having part for my project.
Thanks

Comment: LINQ doesn't have a `having` equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Gert Arnold, that really solved my challenge.